# MYSQL UPDATE only when value also exists in other table

Tags: mysql, pdo

I use the query below to check if there is a row with the `ID`  I  want to insert:

```
INSERT INTO data_advertenties_prijsindicatie (ID_advertentie, 
                                              prijs_indicatie,
                                              eenheid)
       SELECT ID_advertentie, :prijs_indicatie, :eenheid
       FROM data_advertenties
       WHERE ID_advertentie = :ID_advertentie AND 
             unieke_hash_plaatsen = :hash_plaatsen
```

How update on the same way?  I only want to update table `data_advertenties_prijsindicatie` if the '`ID_advertentie`' AND '`unieke_hash_plaatsen`' exist in table `data_advertenties`

Comment: Is there a joining key between the tables I suppose its `ID_advertentie` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use UPDATE with WHERE clause with a subquery

```
UPDATE data_advertenties_prijsindicatie
  SET prijs_indicatie = ..., eenheid = ...
WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT 0 FROM  data_advertenties
   WHERE 
     ID_advertentie = :ID_advertentie AND unieke_hash_plaatsen = :hash_plaatsen
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid of me, just join the table...

```
UPDATE data_advertenties_teksten a
INNER JOIN data_advertenties b ON a.ID_advertentie = b.ID_advertentie 
SET omschrijving_aanbieding = 'te265125st'
WHERE b.ID_advertentie = 109
AND unieke_hash_plaatsen = 'd'
```